# Asp.net web application and ADAM

Tags: active-directory, asp.net

I wonder if this is the right place for my question. I have a Asp.net web application that use Windows authentication and a customer's CTO asked me if there are problems with the application with ADAM (Active Directory Application Mode). I don't know ADAM, I read something googling but it needs specific integration? Thanks